# how to change max file upload size WordPress 4.9.8

Tags: uploads, wp-filesystem

As the title states i have tried it with the htaccess file to change the maximum upload size  and nothing i have even created a php.ini file in the root of the wordpress folder and still nothing can some here please help me.

Comment: i think we can change this upload limit in the server only

Comment: i have full access to it as its hosted on a private ubuntu server

Comment: downvoted as it is impossible to answer without much more details. Anyway it sound like a php configuration question than a wordpress development one. Wordpress itself do not have limits (except for multisite)

Answer (score 1):

php.ini should be in the /wp-admin/ folder, not the root.  Also, I've had success using a combination of the following in my /wp-admin/php.ini file AND a directive to increase the memory in my wp-config.php file, increased memory is needed when uploading larger files.

Put something like this in your php.ini file (change values as you need to):

```
    memory=512MB
    post_max_size=20MB
    upload_max_filesize=50MB
```

Then in your wp-config.php file, add something like this:

```
    define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

The upper memory limit doesn't need to be the same in both, but I find it works best when it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create **.user.ini** in root

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 256M
memory_limit = 500M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_vars = 500M
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: ill try now n let you know

Comment: its not worked but thank you

Comment: Have you check using functions.php ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

Add this in function.php i think this will works

Comment: that didnt work either

Comment: i changed the code check now

Comment: is that the file in the themes folder ??

Comment: yes in your theme folder

Comment: let me know if its worked

Comment: no it didnt work im just havin alook to see if its apache or ubuntu

Comment: one plugin is there to increase the upload size just try it name is: Increase Max Upload Filesize

Comment: i tried it last night n got errors on 90% of my uploads saying they are to big

Comment: i think i may have foound the fault it was within the apache's php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed the problem it was a setting within apache itself i had to change sorry if i have messed you about it wasn't intentional  just happy to have it sorted now

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Thank you for checking back, but please [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/314992/edit) your answer and show the setting that you changed to help future visitors who are searching for the solution to a similar issue. After a couple days, come back and click the check mark next to your answer to mark it as accepted and close out the question.